# Python: call a function from string name

Tags: python

I have a str object for example: `menu = 'install'`. I want to run install method from this string. For example when I call `menu(some, arguments)` it will call `install(some, arguments)`. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: I changed the duplicate link because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/ is narrowly scoped; this question is looking for `install` in an unspecified namespace (but probably intended to be either the local or global namespace), not as an attribute of a module.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If it's in a class, you can use getattr:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def install(self):
          print "In install"

method_name = 'install' # set by the command line options
my_cls = MyClass()

method = None
try:
    method = getattr(my_cls, method_name)
except AttributeError:
    raise NotImplementedError("Class `{}` does not implement `{}`".format(my_cls.__class__.__name__, method_name))

method()
```

or if it's a function:

```
def install():
       print "In install"

method_name = 'install' # set by the command line options
possibles = globals().copy()
possibles.update(locals())
method = possibles.get(method_name)
if not method:
     raise NotImplementedError("Method %s not implemented" % method_name)
method()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if the method is not in a class?

Comment: Thank you so much sdolan. I have tried with **globals** not **locals** and it works.

Comment: The latter does not .copy() globals before mutating it, inviting all sorts of trouble. And it has a bug, since it calls the method immediately before checking it, then calls its result again.

Also, it's common practise to use a prefix, to prevent calling just ANY element in the namespace (e.g. "do_install()").

Comment: @pyroscope: Good catch on the globals.  I've updated the sample code to do that.  I also agree on the prefix, and do that in my own code where it makes sense.  I don't know the specifics of the OPs problem, so I'm trying to not jump to any conclusions.

Comment: @sdolan , Perfect answer but a minor mistake getattr does not respond with None if attribute does not exista rather it raises an exception so
**if not method:
    raise Exception("Method %s not implemented" % method_name)** is not needed

Comment: @Sarathsp: haha good catch. Only took 4.5 years for someone to catch it ;)

Comment: And if you are sure that method exists, you can use: globals().get(method_name)() or locals().get(method_name)()

Comment: Your first answer:
raise NotImplementedError("Class `{}` does not implement `{}`".format(my_cls.__class__.__name__, method_name)

Should be:
raise NotImplementedError("Class `{}` does not implement `{}`".format(my_cls.__class__.__name__, method_name))

Comment: @MoAli cool, just updated to add the extra paren.

Comment: @AlexBenfica what's the difference between calling by globals and locals?

Comment: @Nihat please refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars

Comment: Where should i import NotImplementedError

Answer (score 76):

You can use a dictionary too.

```
def install():
    print "In install"

methods = {'install': install}

method_name = 'install' # set by the command line options
if method_name in methods:
    methods[method_name]() # + argument list of course
else:
    raise Exception("Method %s not implemented" % method_name)
```

Comment: I believe using dictionary is a bit more clean that relying on globals().copy() in accepted answer.

Comment: @AgnivaDeSarker Make sure that in setting up your dictionary, you haven't called the function - i.e., that you use only the function name, with no brackets: `{'install': install}`

Comment: I like this more, as it easy to pass parameters, and you can control the list of methods easily with dictionalry

Comment: I would prefer this approach to the accepted answer but I can't seem to make it work with class methods.

Comment: @navjotk in the declaration of  your dictionary: `methods = {'install': self.install}` (or `obj.install`)

Comment: hmm, i tried something similar here but it wasn't working:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359442/apply-a-method-from-a-list-of-methods-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: If using a dictionary to store the method, the method **must** be defined before the dictionary - as in the method definition must be above the line the dictionary is on or you will get; _"NameError: name 'X' is not defined'_

Answer (score 40):

Why cant we just use eval()?

```
def install():
    print "In install"
```

New method

```
def installWithOptions(var1, var2):
    print "In install with options " + var1 + " " + var2
```

And then you call the method as below

```
method_name1 = 'install()'
method_name2 = 'installWithOptions("a","b")'
eval(method_name1)
eval(method_name2)
```

This gives the output as

```
In install
In install with options a b
```

Comment: He is asking for a way to call the function with arguments. Can you detail?

Comment: Yup it works with arguments as well in the same manner.

Comment: If you are using the above-mentioned strategy, it means that you are dynamically defining your methods/functions, in other words, they can be a lot of things, including malicious code. I suggest you [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and then, never using eval again. When needed, just use `json`.

Comment: @lucastamoios: Not true at least in case of OP - using predefined strings as function names.

Comment: How do you suggest building the argument list for an arbitrary list of arguments with `installWithOptions`? Showing the hard coded example certainly doesn't tell the story here. 

This is all of course ignoring how horrible of a practice using eval is in the first place. I've never seen a legitimate use case for it

Comment: eval() is safe to use if the input can be trusted

Comment: @Justas Sure. In theory. But now that code is there forever, and a change that seems harmless in another file now turns out to open a giant security hole because of the use of an eval statement. You should build around as few assumption as possible. Because who knows when they'll change.

Comment: `eval(method_name1)(a,b)` also works. Fair point about safety-- ok for tiny private scripts but do they stay that way? Take great care if the string is coming from a website, for example. It isn't `eval` that's the only problem here-- using `getattr` on a string from an arbitrary source is just as dangerous.

Comment: **Do not ever use `eval` on data that could possibly ever come from outside the program. It is a security hole that allows whoever creates that data to run arbitrary Python code on your computer. No, you cannot practically sandbox it.**