# What's the difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?

Tags: python

What is the difference between `globals()`, `locals()`, and `vars()`?  What do they return?  Are updates to the results useful?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Each of these return a dictionary:

- `globals()` *always* returns the dictionary of the *module* namespace
- `locals()` *always* returns *a* dictionary of the *current* namespace
- `vars()` returns *either a* dictionary of the current namespace (if called with no argument) or *the* dictionary of the argument.

`locals` and `vars` could use some more explanation.  If `locals()` is called inside a function, it updates a dict with the values of the current local variable namespace (plus any closure variables) as of that moment and returns it. Multiple calls to `locals()` in the same stack frame return the same dict each time - it's attached to the stack frame object as its `f_locals` attribute. The dict's contents are updated on each `locals()` call and each `f_locals` attribute access, but *only* on such calls or attribute accesses. It does not automatically update when variables are assigned, and assigning entries in the dict will not assign the corresponding local variables:

```
import inspect

def f():
    x = 1
    l = locals()
    print(l)
    locals()
    print(l)
    x = 2
    print(x, l['x'])
    l['x'] = 3
    print(x, l['x'])
    inspect.currentframe().f_locals
    print(x, l['x'])

f()
```

gives us:

```
{'x': 1}
{'x': 1, 'l': {...}}
2 1
2 3
2 2
```

The first `print(l)` only shows an `'x'` entry, because the assignment to `l` happens after the `locals()` call. The second `print(l)`, after calling `locals()` again, shows an `l` entry, even though we didn't save the return value. The third and fourth `print`s show that assigning variables doesn't update `l` and vice versa, but after we access `f_locals`, local variables are copied into `locals()` again.

Two notes:

1. This behavior is CPython specific -- other Pythons may allow the updates to make it back to the local namespace automatically.
2. In CPython 2.x it is possible to make this work by putting an `exec "pass"` line in the function. This switches the function to an older, slower execution mode that uses the `locals()` dict as the canonical representation of local variables.

If `locals()` is called *outside* a function it returns the actual dictionary that is the current namespace.  Further changes to the namespace *are* reflected in the dictionary, and changes to the dictionary *are* reflected in the namespace:

```
class Test(object):
    a = 'one'
    b = 'two'
    huh = locals()
    c = 'three'
    huh['d'] = 'four'
    print huh
```

gives us:

```
{
  'a': 'one',
  'b': 'two',
  'c': 'three',
  'd': 'four',
  'huh': {...},
  '__module__': '__main__',
}
```

So far, everything I've said about `locals()` is also true for `vars()`... here's the difference:  `vars()` accepts a single object as its argument, and if you give it an object it returns the `__dict__` of that object.  For a typical object, its `__dict__` is where most of its attribute data is stored. This includes class variables and module globals:

```
class Test(object):
    a = 'one'
    b = 'two'
    def frobber(self):
        print self.c
t = Test()
huh = vars(t)
huh['c'] = 'three'
t.frobber()
```

which gives us:

```
three
```

Note that a function's `__dict__` is its attribute namespace, not local variables. It wouldn't make sense for a function's `__dict__` to store local variables, since recursion and multithreading mean there can be multiple calls to a function at the same time, each with their own locals:

```
def f(outer):
    if outer:
        f(False)
        print('Outer call locals:', locals())
        print('f.__dict__:', f.__dict__)
    else:
        print('Inner call locals:', locals())
        print('f.__dict__:', f.__dict__)

f.x = 3

f(True)
```

which gives us:

```
Inner call locals: {'outer': False}
f.__dict__: {'x': 3}
Outer call locals: {'outer': True}
f.__dict__: {'x': 3}
```

Here, `f` calls itself recursively, so the inner and outer calls overlap. Each one sees its own local variables when it calls `locals()`, but both calls see the same `f.__dict__`, and `f.__dict__` doesn't have any local variables in it.

Comment: The part "and any assignments to the dictionary are not reflected in the actual local namespace" might be worded [a bit to definite](http://ideone.com/7RtOi).

Comment: Oddly enough, you can access variables added to to a `vars()` or `locals()` dictionary called within a function if you use `eval()`. EG: `def test(): huh = locals(); huh['d'] = 4; print eval('d')` prints 4 when `test()` is executed!

Comment: Actually assignment to the `dict` (returned by `locals()`) happens to be reflected in the local namespace and changes to the local namespace happens to be reflected in the `dict` (in my python). The only thing is that the specification does not guarantee this behaviour.

Comment: Term *name scope* usage looks more easy for me than *namespace*.

Comment: `vars` is coming from `__builtins__` module without importing that module(magic). Where is `locals` & `globals` coming from?

Comment: @overexchange: *namespace* is the Python term; `locals` and `globals` are also in `__builtins__`.

Comment: @overexchange: `import this` and in google `site:docs.python.org namespace`

Comment: can one update any of these in python 3 and have the script actually work?

Comment: @CharlieParker:  You'll need to ask that as it's own question.  The answer is both yes and no, depending on exactly what your script is trying to do.

Comment: Is there a scenario where you need to use any of these? I never used any of them so I wonder in what situation would you have no way around using them?

Comment: @CalvinKu : Well, depends on what you mean "no way around those" - in Python, there are always more ways, how to achieve something.
However, as an example - right now I'm writing evaluation script of student code's and I need to make sure, they don't change local variables during their run. The best way is to get a copy of variables before their call, get a copy of variables after the call and compare them.

Comment: Could you speak a bit about the module namespace? Thanks

Comment: @EthanFurman How does one access f_locals attribute of a particular frame object directly?