# Assignment order matters unexpectedly with "exec expr in globals(), locals()"

Tags: python, global-variables, eval

The following code in Python 2.X prints "a : 2" as you'd expect:

```
def f():
  #a = 1
  exec "a = 2" in globals(), locals()
  for k,v in locals().items(): print k,":",v
  #a = 3

f()
```

But if you uncomment the "a = 1" then it prints "a : 1", as I didn't expect.
Even weirder, if you uncomment the "a = 3" line then it doesn't print anything at all, which I definitely didn't expect (I had a baffling bug that I distilled down to that).

I think the answer is buried in the documentation on locals() and globals(), or maybe in other questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars) but I thought it was worth calling this manifestation out.

I'd love to learn what the Python interpreter is thinking here, as well as suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: What a charming way of adding a key-value to a dictionary: `exec "a=2" in globals(), dic` :)

Answer (score 2):

The old Python 2's `exec` would change the bytecode to search both the local and the global namespaces.

As you define the `a = 2` in global, this is the one found when `a = 1` is commented. When you uncomment `a = 3`, this is the `a` "found" but not defined yet.

If you read how symbol tables are processed in this [great article by Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/), you can better understand how local variables are processed.

You shouldn't use `exec` for this kind of code (I hope this is not production code) and it will break anyway when you port your code to Py3k:

Python 3's `exec` function is no longer a statement and, therefore, can't change the environment it is situated.

---

Probably I should go directly to the point:

If you are doing all this dynamic naming stuff, you should use a dictionary:

```
def f():
    data = {'a': 1}
    data['a'] = 2
    if ...:
        data['a'] = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions for workarounds? How would you do an eval that sets a local variable?

Comment: @dreeves Use a dictionary instead: `data = {'a': 1}; data['a'] = 2`

Comment: Ironically I started with a dictionary but wanted to use the values in some messy expressions so I wanted to create a local variable for every key in the dict so I could say, for example, "a" instead of "data['a']". (So my hideous solution does accomplish that, as long as I don't assign to those local variables either before or after the execs!)

Comment: @dreeves unfortunately you'll have to add a few keystrokes to each variable you dynamically change to make your code work as expected. `exec` is a tool to be used in very special cases.

Answer (score 1):

from `locals` function [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals):

**Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

checking:

```
>>> def f():
    a = 1
    print(locals())
    locals()['a']=2
    print(a,locals())


>>> f()
{'a': 1}
1 {'a': 1}
```

So you just cant modify local context through the `locals()` function

Comment: You can't modify it directly, but `exec`-ed code can modify it.

Comment: @BrenBarn It does only in python 2.X. But if context is specified explicitly it modifies the supplied dict only. In that case **locals()** is just copy of the local context and it's modification doesn't affect original.

Comment: @hayden And because of that there is the **Note**. Changes may or may not affect local variables.