# Any difference between dir() and locals() in Python?

Tags: python

According to Python documentation, both `dir()` (without args) and `locals()` evaluates to the list of variables in something called `local scope`. First one returns list of names, second returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. Is it the only difference? Is this always valid?

```
assert dir() == sorted( locals().keys() )
```

Comment: Related post - [What's the difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7969949/465053)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `dir()` when called without arguments is almost same as `locals()`, but `dir()` returns a list of strings  and `locals()` returns a dictionary and you can update that dictionary to add new variables.

```
dir(...)
    dir([object]) -> list of strings

    If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.


locals(...)
    locals() -> dictionary

    Update and return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.
```

---

Type:

```
>>> type(locals())
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(dir())
<type 'list'>
```

---

Update or add new variables using `locals()`:

```
In [2]: locals()['a']=2

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 2
```

using `dir()`, however, this doesn't work:

```
In [7]: dir()[-2]
Out[7]: 'a'

In [8]: dir()[-2]=10

In [9]: dir()[-2]
Out[9]: 'a'

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 2
```

Comment: Due to the way Python optimizes access to local variables in functions, it is often not possible to change local variables using the `locals()` dictionary, which is why the documentation warns against it.

Comment: @kindall is right -- you should consider `locals()` read-only.

Answer (score 0):

> Exact question is 'what function to use in order to check if some variable is defined in local scope'.

Accessing an undefined variable in Python raises an exception:

```
>>> undefined
NameError: name 'undefined' is not defined
```

Just like any other exception, you can catch it:

```
try:
    might_exist
except NameError:
    # Variable does not exist
else:
    # Variable does exist
```

> I need to know language architecture to write better code.

That won't make your code better. You should *never* get yourself into a situation where such a thing is required, it's almost always the wrong approach.