# difference between locals() and globals() and dir() in python

Tags: python

assume this code :

```
>>> iterator=filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, [2, 18, 9, 22, 17, 24, 8, 12, 27])
>>> x=int()
>>> locals()
{'__package__': None, '__spec__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'iterator': <filter object at 0x02E732B0>, 'x': 0, '__doc__': None}
>>> globals()
{'__package__': None, '__spec__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'iterator': <filter object at 0x02E732B0>, 'x': 0, '__doc__': None}
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'iterator', 'x']
>>>
```

what is the difference between locals,globals and dir ? and what is the usage ?

Comment: Some related questions: ["What's the difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars) and ["Any difference between dir() and locals() in Python?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918189/any-difference-between-dir-and-locals-in-python)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At global scope , both `locals()` and `globals()` return the same dictionary to global namespace . But inside a function , `locals()` returns the **copy** to the local namespace , whereas `globals()` would return global namespace (which would contain the global names) . So the difference between them is only visible when in a function . Example to show this -

```
>>> locals() == globals() #global scope, that is directly within the script (not inside a function.
True
>>> def a():
...     l = 1
...     print('locals() :',locals())
...     print('globals() :',globals())
...
>>> a()
locals() : {'l': 1}
globals() : {'BOTTOM': 'bottom', 'PROJECTING': 'proj....
```

From [documentation of `globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) -

> **globals()**
>
> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

From [documentation of `locals()` -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)

> **locals()**
>
> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.
>
> Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

To answer the question about *usage* , one usage is to be able to access variables/names using string for that. For example if you have a variable named `a` , and you want to access its value using the string - `'a'` , you can use `globals()` or `locals()` for that as - `globals()['a']` , this would return you the value of global variable `a` or `locals()['a']` would return you the value of `a` in current namespace (which is global namespace when directly inside the script, or local namespace if inside a function)

`dir()` shows a list of attributes for the object passed in as argument , without an argument it returns the list of names in the current local namespace (similar to locals().keys() ) . From [documentation of `dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) -

> **dir([object])**
>
> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

Answer (score 8):

You can notice the difference between `locals` and `globals` if you try to execute them inside a function. If you try to run them from the console without creating nested scopes the obvious result is that you wouldn't be able to notice any difference.

- `locals` returns you a dictionary of variables declared in the local scope : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals
- `globals` returns you a dictionary of variables declared in the global scope : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals
- `dir` works in a similar way to `locals` if you don't provide arguments, but if you pass an object as an argument, then it returns you a list of valid attributes for that object: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 2):

In global scope (such as at the interactive prompt), your `locals` and `globals` are the same. However, inside a function, they are different:

```
x = 'some'
y = 'this'

def foo(x):
    y = 'that'
    print "My locals: ", `locals()`
    print "My globals: ", `globals()`

# locals has x: other and y: that only
# globals contains x: some, y: this and many more global names
foo('other')
```

The global variable `x` with the value 'some' is a different variable from the local variable `x` with the value 'other' (and the same for the two variables named `y`).

Check [the builtins documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) for details, or the documentation on Python's scope rules.

And `dir()` without arguments is essentially the same as `locals().keys()` (the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir): *Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope.*)

Comment: +1 on the last point: len(locals())==len(dir()), and in the global scope or in the interpreter, it's also equal to len(globals()). (Side note, if using ipython interpreter, beware it continuously add/save local variables.)

Answer (score 1):

`globals()` returns the symbols in the current global namespace (scope of current module + built-ins) in a `dict`-object with `(key, value)`-pairs. `key` is a string with the name of the symbol and `value` is the value of the symbol itself (e.g. the number `1`, another `dict`, a function, a class, etc.)

`locals()` returns the symbols in the current local namespace (scope of function). This will give the same result as `globals()` when called on module level.

`dir()` (without parameters) returns a list of names from the current local namespace.

When you run the following three commands on module level, they have the same values:

```
>>> sorted(locals().keys())
['A', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'loc']
>>> sorted(dir())
['A', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'loc']
>>> sorted(globals().keys())
['A', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'loc']
```

If these three calls are made a function `locals().keys()` and `dir()` have the same values but `globals()` differs.

```
>>> def A():
...   print(sorted(locals().keys()))
...   print(sorted(dir()))
...   print(sorted(globals().keys()))

>>> A()
[]
[]
['A', 'B', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'loc']
```

You can see the difference in use the use of `globals()` and `locals()`.

## But what about dir()?

The point of `dir()` is, that it accepts an object as paramater. It will return a list of attribute names of that object. You can use it e.g. to inspect an object at runtime.

If we take the example above with the function `A()`, we could call:

```
>>> dir(A)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
```

and get all the attributes of the function object `A`.

There are some more details about `dir()` at: [Difference between dir(…) and vars(…).keys() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980249/difference-between-dir-and-vars-keys-in-python)