# Python3 globals() and locals() contents

Tags: python, python-3.5, global

In my Python3 learning, while trying out globals() and locals(), I made a very basic, stand-alone Python program and received results **for which I ask for expert explanation**.

I then executed the same 2 functions inside my Python program (any) and received a list of many (all ?) values in my program, regardless if it was declared local or global or non.
My understanding was that the globals() functions holds a list of all values that were declared as globals (same for locals), but according to my observation, the results show something different.
Can anyone explain what I see and why?

Here is the program and the results:

The python program:

```
 print("Globals=",globals())
 print("Locals=",locals())
```

The result (for the above 2-lines program):

```
=============== RESTART: /home/pi/Junk/globals_locals_test.py ==========
Globals= {'__package__': None, '__spec__': None, '__loader__': <class '
_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__doc__': None, '__file__': '
/home/pi/Junk/globals_locals_test.py', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins'
 (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__'}
Locals= {'__package__': None, '__spec__': None, '__loader__': <class '
_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__doc__': None, '__file__': '
/home/pi/Junk/globals_locals_test.py', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins'
 (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__'}
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between locals() and globals() and dir() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003472/difference-between-locals-and-globals-and-dir-in-python)

Comment: Yes, this is a very detailed explanation that partially answers my question, mainly the 'hows' but not the 'whys'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple explanation

`globals()` refers to the current modules' attribute dictionary.
`locals()` refers to the current local variables in your function/code-snippet.

Setting a variable will *only* ever change `locals()`. (Unless you tell python otherwise using the `global` or `nonlocal` keyword.)

**Here an example**

By default on module-scope globals is the same dict as locals:

```
>>> globals() is locals()
True
```

Since globals is locals in this case, modifying the locals will also modify the globals.

If you create a function and look at locals in there, you will see that locals will differ

```
>>> def test():
...    print("globals is locals:", globals() is locals())
...    print("globals:", globals())
...    print("locals:", locals())
>>> test()
globals is locals: False
globals: {'__name__': '__main__', ...}
locals: {}
```

Locals will automatically update when you change a function-local variable

```
>>> def test2():
...     print("locals 1:", locals())
...     x = 1
...     print("locals 2:", locals())
>>> test2()
locals 1: {}
locals 2: {'x': 1}
```

Something similar happens when creating new classes

```
>>> class Test:
...     print("locals:", locals())
locals: {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Test'}
```

---

### More in-depth explanation

If you want to know why globals and locals are the way they are let's look at what happens under the hood of Python.

**Some ground work**

All python code passes what equates to the `eval` or `exec` function at some point. These functions accept three parameters: `source`, `globals` (defaults to current globals) and `locals` (defaults to current locals).

The function `globals()` and `locals()` will return whatever has been passed into the `eval` or `exec` functions shown above.

**What does the Python Shell do?**

If you do

```
>>> print(globals())
```

The REPL will internally do something along the lines of

```
# This variable stores your globals.
_my_main_module = {}

def exec_some_line(line):
    return eval(line, globals=_my_main_module, locals=_my_main_module)

# ...

exec_some_line("print(globals())")
```

As you can see, the Python Shell will at some point set `globals` and `locals` to the same dict.

**Function execution**

Internally, function execution will essentially do three things:

1. Parse the arguments passed to the function and add them to the local variables.
2. Execute the code of the function
3. Return its result.

Here a pseudo-algorithm:

```
def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
    local_variables = parse_signature_with_args(args, kwargs)
    exec(function_source, function_globals, local_variables)
    return function_result
```

**Creating new classes**

When using the class-statement, all indented code will be executed separately.

1. a new dictionary is created that will act as `locals()`
2. Your code is executed with said locals.
3. The class is created passing locals in

If you execute this code:

```
class Test:
   a = 5
```

This is approximately what happens:

```
 # 1. A new dictionary is created
 _dict = type.__prepare__()
 _dict["__module__"] = __name__
 _dict["__qualname__"] = "Test"

 # 2. Execute the code
 exec("a = 5", globals=globals(), locals=_dict)

 # 3. A class is created
 Test = type("Test", (), _dict)
```

**How this maps to module imports**

If you import a module an intricate import mechanism starts. This is a simplified overview:

1. The interpreter will look if the module has already been imported.
2. The interpreter will find the file.
3. Then the file is read and parsed
4. A module object is created.
5. The python script is executed and its globals and locals will be set to the new modules' `__dict__` attribute.
6. The module object is returned.

It works something like this:

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType
def __import__(name):
    # 1. See if module is already imported
    if name in sys.modules:
       return sys.modules[name]

    # 2. Find file.
    filename = find_out_path_to_file(name)

    # 3. Read and parse file
    with open(filename) as f:
      script = f.read()

    # 4. Create the new module
    module = ModuleType(name)

    # 5. Execute the code of the module.
    exec(script, globals=module.__dict__, locals=module.__dict__)

    # 6. Return the new module.
    return module
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks.
Although it will require deeper investigation and more time to digest the details, it answers my question.

Comment: Thank you. Please accept my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Python doesn't actually use the `locals()` dict for local variable lookup most of the time, though. Inside a function, writes to `locals()` won't affect local variables, and writes to local variables won't affect the local variable dict until you call `locals()` again.

Comment: Interesting observation. Didn't think of that. It becomes especially clear when looking at the disassembled function. Good catch. Have a +1.