# Inner workings of 'global' variable assignment

Tags: python, global

I have a questions regarding the inner workings of the global statement in Python.
With the syntax

```
def f():
    global x
    x = 1
```

Variable `x` is turned into a global variable appears in `globals()` and is accessible outside of `f`. So far understood.

Until now I assumed, that with `global x` the name `x` is defined and should reference to a memory address, however if `x` is not initialized, such as

```
def f():
    global x
id(x)
```

a `name "x" not defined` error pops up.

Therefore I am wondering what immediate effect the `global x` line has in the background,as neither `locals, globals, vars` seem to be affected by the line shown by the comparison below:

```
def test():
    global x
    print("Vars")
    print([i for i in vars().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Globals")
    print([i for i in globals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Locals")
    print([i for i in locals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    x = 1
    print("Vars")
    print([i for i in vars().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Globals")
    print([i for i in globals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Locals")
    print([i for i in locals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    
test()
```

After `global x` the scopes are all empty, and after assignment, `x` is rightfully set as `global`.

```
Vars
[]
Globals
['In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', 'test']
Locals
[]
Vars
[]
Globals
['In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', 'test', 'x']
Locals
[]
```

```
def test():
    print("Vars")
    print([i for i in vars().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Globals")
    print([i for i in globals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Locals")
    print([i for i in locals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    x = 1
    print("Vars")
    print([i for i in vars().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Globals")
    print([i for i in globals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    print("Locals")
    print([i for i in locals().keys() if i[0] != "_"])
    
test()
```

Without `global x` it is `local`

```
Vars
[]
Globals
['In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', 'test']
Locals
[]
Vars
['x']
Globals
['In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', 'test']
Locals
['x']
```

So basically the question is, where the heck does python save the information of `x` going to be `global` between definition and assignment.

Comment: The line `global x` has no immediate effect. It doesn't define `x`. It simply tells the interpreter that when you use `x` you're intending to refer to a global variable named `x` instead of a local one. It should be separately defined at the module scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310792/python3-globals-and-locals-contents

Comment: Why do you expect this information to be exposed at runtime?  `global` tells the interpreter how to interpret future references to `x`, but by itself is not required to have any observable side effects.  Somewhat similar to how the line `x: int` does nothing by itself, but still can produce linting errors if followed by `x = ''`.