# check the existence of variable python

Tags: python, variables

```
if VAR in globals():
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

I got this error:

```
  File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Project_Nuôi_FB/te1.py", line 2, in <module>
    if VAR in globals():
NameError: name 'VAR' is not defined
```

How do I check the existence of a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose your `VAR` by quotes:

```
if 'VAR' in globals():
#  ^---^--- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` return a dictionary with string keys. Thus to check if a variable named `VAR` is defined you need to do the following:

```
if 'VAR' in globals():
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotation marks around variable name:

```
if 'VAR' in globals():
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dir`:

```
if 'VAR' in dir():
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Comment: The output `dir()` and `globals()` can be different: [difference between locals() and globals() and dir() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32003472/2745495])