# How to Access dictionary from other file on run time

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to access a dictionary created in file1.py from file2.py based on value passed in a variable. Both files in same directory.

### File1.py looks like

```
dict_test_1 = {'a':1, 'b': 2}

dict_test_2 = {'a':11, 'b': 12}
```

### file2.py looks like:

```
import file1

def fun(dict_name):

    var_a = file1.dict_name['a'] ## I wanted an equivalent of file1.dict_test_1['a'] or file.dict_test_2['a']
```

fun(deciding variable which is coming from run time) # Calling function

I need to access either of dictionary created in file1.py at run time by 'dict_name' but the problem is python actually sees 'dict_name' as it one of the dictionary defined in file1.py instead of taking value of 'dict_value' variable passed in function 'fun' and looking for corresponding dictionary.

Any solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access a python object by value, you've got to deal with the kludge of `vars` or `object__dict__`.

You have a string `dict_name` that will correspond to the name of a python object inside the module `file1`. If `file1` was a dictionary, you'd do `file1[dict_name]`, right? That's where `__dict__` comes in.

```
def fun(dict_name):
    selected_dict = file1.__dict__[dict_name]
    var_a = selected_dict['a']
```

This is similarly written by using the `vars` built-in. It is better explained [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars)

```
def fun(dict_name):
    selected_dict = vars(file1)[dict_name]
    var_a = selected_dict['a']
```

Comment: Thank you @Adam Smith. That helped me. It worked out both ways (Vars and __dict__) Thanks for new lesson.

Comment: @user2033758 right, because `vars(some_object)` returns `some_object.__dict__` (just like `len(some_list)` returns `some_list.__len__()`)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
def fun(dict_name):
    selected_dict = {'dict_test_1': file1.dict_test_1,
                     'dict_test_2': file1.dict_test_2 }

    var_a = file1.selected_dict[dict_name]['a']
```

Comment: Although this is great if you can know for certain which dicts will exist in `file1`, it's tough to generalize that. Unfortunately this is one of those times where using `vars` or `module.__dict__` is the correct approach

Comment: Yep, this would be an other way. I assumed the OP knows the dictionaries in advance. Please feel free to provide alternative way.