# how to get string itself as a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried in all ways, could not get any solution for it.

I'm stuck in an application, i will give similar example ,

i have some strings,

```
arg = "school"
arg_2 = "college"

school = "enjoy"
college = "study"
```

i want to use it in code as below

```
if ( arg == arg  )
  \\ want to print content of school here, 
else
  \\ want to print content of college here,
```

can i make it with the help of string 'arg' only? i don't want to use the name of string 'school' here.
is there any method to do that?

Comment: `if ( arg == arg  )` despite the redundant parentheses is **always** true: any object always equals itself.  This essentially makes it impossible to gauge **what** you're actually asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`locals`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7969949/1860929) to do this

```
>>> arg = "school"
>>> arg_2 = "college"
>>> school = "enjoy"
>>> college = "study"
>>> locals()[arg]
'enjoy'
>>> locals()[arg_2]
'study'
```

So you could simply print a statement like

```
>>> "{} at {}".format(locals()[arg], arg)
'enjoy at school'
>>> "{} at {}".format(locals()[arg_2], arg_2)
'study at college'
```

PS: doing `arg == arg` is completely redundant, it will always evaluate to True

Comment: yeah, that was on oversight for equating arg to arg, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your goal is to get indirect access to values.  In that case, consider putting your variables in a class or a dictionary.  Here is an example of the class approach:

```
class mydata(object):
    arg = "school"
    arg_2 = "college"

    school = "enjoy"
    college = "study"

    def value_of_value(self, s):
        return getattr(self, getattr(self, s))

x = mydata()
print 'arg->', x.value_of_value('arg')
print 'arg_2->', x.value_of_value('arg_2')
```

This produces:

```
arg-> enjoy
arg_2-> study
```