# Creating an attribute using string as a name

Tags: python

Is it possible to create an attribute where attribute name is specified by a string

E.g.

```
create_attribute(QtGui.QLineEdit, 'myname')
self.myname.setText = 'created!'
```

That is

```
create_attribute(QtGui.QLineEdit, 'myname')
```

equals to

```
self.myname = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
```

I have already questioned similar question [Creating an object using string as a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966015/creating-an-object-using-string-as-a-name) but just to realise it does not solve my second problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an object using string as a name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966015/creating-an-object-using-string-as-a-name)

Comment: `create_attribute` doesn't know `self`. So not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setattr`:

```
setattr(self, 'myname', QtGui.QLineEdit(self))
```

to get the attribute, you can use `getattr`:

```
getattr(self, 'myname').setText('bla')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__setattr__()` to set the attribute using `string` .

Example -

```
class CA:
    pass

c = CA()
c.__setattr__('name','value')
c.__setattr__('myname',QtGui.QLineEdit)
c.name
>> 'value'
```