# Equivalent of getfenv in Python?

Tags: python, lua

What would be the equivalent to getfenv() in Python? Is there a way to get all available functions/variables in an environment?

Trying to see if something is sandboxed or not, which is why I am wondering this.

Comment: [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: What do you mean by sandboxed?

Comment: nevermind, just looked at [lua documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-getfenv), I think you can get info on a specific stack frame by using `sys._getframe` and then inspecting the frame object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars for more on these topics.

Comment: This question would be more useful if you said explicitly what *information* you want, instead of asking for the same information as a function in some other language. There probably isn't a single, exact equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `globals()`

```
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> foo = 1
>>> def bar():
...   pass
... 
>>> globals()
{'bar': <function bar at 0x102dd30c8>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': 1, '__doc__': None}
```