# How to make a global inside two functions

Tags: python-3.x

```
import getpass
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

def register():
    username = str(input('username '))
    password = str(getpass.getpass('password ',stream=None))
    exec('global '+username)
    exec(username+'=user('+"'"+username+"'"+','+"'"+password+"'"+')')

def hashPassword(password):
    Passhash = sha256_crypt.hash(password)
    return Passhash

def verifyPassword(password,hashpass):
    return sha256_crypt.verify(password,hashpass)

class user(object):
    users=[]
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        password = str(password)
        if len(password) <= 20:
            self.username = username
            user.users.append(username)
            self.password = hashPassword(password)
        else:
            print("No more than 20 characters in the password")  

def login(username, passsword):
    if username in user.users:
        if verifyPassword(password,exec(username+'.password'))==True:
            print('logged in.')
        else:
            print('wrong password')
    else:
       print('unknown user.')
```

I am trying to make a text based login/register system since I am fairly new to coding. For some reason something with the `register()` function doesn't correctly register a user because when I go to login `verifypassword()` it says

```
if verifyPassword(password,exec(username+'.password'))==True:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
>>>
```

if someone could tell me what is happening. I think it it something with global variables but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of `exec` in your functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `global` in `exec` doesn't work.

Use `globals()[var_name] = var_value` to set dynamic variable names in global scope.

`exec` is <del>gererally</del> a (very) [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars) [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) if called with user-supplied input.
 It also has (more or less) unexpected bahaviour in functions, see this example:

```
def f():
    exec('a=3')
    print(a)

>>> f()
Traceback [...]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

(This has something to do with local scope being known at compile-time, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451827/python-local-variable-compile-principle) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars))

Also, you might consider storing the actual `user` objects in `user.users` -- this prevents users picking names that you actually use inside your code and prevents unexpected behavior

#### Edit: Elaboration on the "local scope known at compile-time"

Since the compiler knows what local variables you are using, access is by the bytecode `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` instructions, which store and load to and from a kind of array (you can look at local variable names via `f.__code__.co_varnames`), you can't just add stuff dynamically.

Why is this relevant for `global`?

Well, as said above, the `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` instructions are used (you guessed it, for speed), the bytecode for following function will be:

```
>>> def f():
    exec('global x')
    x = 3

>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (exec)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('global x')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first part deals with calling `exec`. The second part is the assignment. `STORE_FAST` assigns to a *local* variable `x`, no matter what `exec` just did.

This is also the reason creating new local variables in `exec` doesn't work: there just isn't space for them. Note this isn't valid for local variables set in `exec` but also "normally", they will have space assigned nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is a dictionary of global-variables, that you can access by calling `globals()`. I'm not sure why `exec(...)` doesn't work, but I would consider a different solution than storing users as variables, named by username. But to solve your problem, keeping this design-choice, you can set the global user like this: `globals()[username] = user(username, password)` and when loggin in, do `verifyPassword(password, globals()[username].password)`.

But since globals is really just a dictionary, it might be better practice to maintain a dictionary of users yourself. A user could potentially overwrite a global variable, by choosing a username that clashes with another global variable. You could then also eliminate the static `users` list on your `user` class. It could look like this, where `repository` is your dictionary with users:

```
import hashlib
import base64
import uuid
import getpass
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

repository = {}

def register():
    username = str(input('username '))
    password = str(getpass.getpass('password ',stream=None))
    repository[username] = user(username, password)

def hashPassword(password):
    Passhash = sha256_crypt.hash(password)
    return Passhash

def verifyPassword(password,hashpass):
    return sha256_crypt.verify(password,hashpass)

class user(object):
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        password = str(password)
        if len(password) <= 20:
            self.username = username
            self.password = hashPassword(password)
        else:
            print("No more than 20 characters in the password")

def loginUser(username):
    if username == 'exit':
        start()
    if username in repository:
        if loginPass(username)==True:
            print('success')
        else:
            print('passfail')        
    else:
        print('incorrect login USERNAME NOT IN USER.USERS LIST')

def loginPass(username):
    password = getpass.getpass('password ',stream=None)
    if verifyPassword(password, repository[username].password) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def start():
    while 1:
        key1=input('login or register (l/r)')
        if key1=='register':
            del key1
            register()
        elif key1=='r':
            del key1
            register()
        elif key1=='l':
            del key1
            loginUser(input('username or exit to got to l/r screen '))

        else:
            print('ERROR string not reconised among ifs') 

start()
```