# Problem importing a function within another function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have two files, blah.py containing

```
def blah():
    print("External blah")
    return "6"
```

and test.py containing

```
def blah():
    print("Internal blah")
    return "5"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        from blah import blah
    except:
        pass
    num = blah()
    print(num)
```

When I run this, I get

```
External blah
6
```

When I make blah.py inaccessible by renaming it to blaat.py, I get

```
Internal blah
5
```

Now, if I change test.py to

```
def blah():
    print("Internal blah")
    return "5"

def blater():
    try:
        from blah import blah
    except:
        pass
    num = blah()
    print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        from blater import blater
    except:
        pass
    blater()
```

it works when blah.py is accessible, but I get an error message when blah.py is not accessible:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    blater()
  File "./test.py", line 16, in blater
    num = blah()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'blah' referenced before assignment
```

Why is that? What subtle difference in calling a function am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link [Python local variable compile principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451827/python-local-variable-compile-principle) should help you to understand what happens (all three answers and comments are helpful).

To summarize, the names are added to a scope during compilation and not during excution. Therefore, in your example, even if import fails, the name will be added to the scope.

In the first case, it's not a problem cause the name `blah` (create by function's definition in `test.py`) and the name `blah` (create by import statement) are in the same scope.

In the second case, the name `blah` (create by function's definition in `test.py`) is added to the **global** scope and the name `blah` (create by import statement) is added to the **`blater`'s local** scope. So, even if the import fail, there is still the name `blah` in the `blater`'s **local** scope and it prevents Python to search `blah` in **global** scope. Since `blah` has not been set, the `UnboundLocalError` is thrown.

If you want to go deeper into the subject, here is some links which helped me to better understand :

[Introduction to python bytecode](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/introduction-python-bytecode)

[dis module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html)

[inspect module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html)

[Python Data model](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html) (to understand how names are stored)