# Python: When variable and class have the same name: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I wrote the following Python code for illustration:

```
class foo:
    def foo_function(self):
      return 1

class bar:
    def bar_function(self):
        foo = foo()
        return foo.foo_function()

bar = bar()
print(bar.bar_function())
```

where in class `bar` I need to use class `foo`. I got the following error when I run it:

```
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

This error comes from the line `foo = foo()` where the variable and class have the same name,
and it will go away if use different names, but I would like to know what happened internally,
please note `bar = bar()` is okay.

By the way, is this the right way to use one class from another class. I use separate class because they are independent: for example, `foo` is to get secret stored on the AWS, and `bar` uses the secret in a different app not related to the AWS at all.

Comment: Try `b = bar()` and `f = foo()` instead to see what happens.

Comment: @quamrana `foo = foo()` needs different names but `bar = bar()` does not, that is why I need to know what happens internally.

Comment: @VPfB Then how the interpreter knows in the case of `bar = bar()`?

Comment: @puravidaso because local `foo` "shadows" the global `foo`. I deleted my original comment, because now I see it was not clear and more space is needed to explain it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [hilton92's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65707084/14033765) is correct. You may want to see also the [python FAQ regarding the UnboundLocalError](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

But the most important thing is, that what you are doing is a bad idea, because it makes your code confusing and doesn't follow any best practices guidelines.

I suggest you to read the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is overusing the python namespace.

Each variable that is saved into memory is allocated a `name` to refer and retrieve it within each scope (function, global etc.)

So looking down the file from top to bottom

1. globally the class `foo` is created and `foo` points to this class
2. globally the class `bar` is created
3. Within `bar`, the global namespace persists, so `foo` still points to the class defined beforehand.
4. However when the class is created, the line `foo = foo()` tells the class that `foo` is a variable in the function and a new link in the namespace is created to use `foo` for that variable, and the link (at least within the `bar` class) to the `foo` class is lost
5. Then `bar` tried to call `foo`, but there is an empty variable related to the name `foo`

Best practice is to:

1. Avoid namespace collisions, just use different variable names
2. use capitalization for classes i.e.

```
class Foo():
 def foo_func():
  return 1

foo = Foo()
```

Note that even though

```
bar = bar()
```

is ok and runs, you can no longer access the `class bar` version of `bar` because the name `bar` has been overwritten, so `bar2 = bar()` will fail

Try this to see what's happening with the namespace

```
class foo:
    def foo_function(self):
        return 1

print('after class foo')
print(str(foo))

class bar:
 def bar_function(self):

  print('in bar')
  print(str(foo))

  foo = foo()
  return foo.foo_function()

print('after class bar')
print(str(foo))
print(str(bar))

bar = bar()

print('after instantiating bar')
print(str(bar))

bar.bar_function()
```

Comment: if "bar" class does not know "foo" class (it should as I tell Python it is a class with "foo()"), then how come it knows when I assign it to a different variable, for example, "foo_in_var=foo()"?

Comment: Once the line `foo=foo()` is called, then the pointer in the namespace of `foo -> class foo` is replaced within `bar` by `foo -> variable foo`. And so `bar` doesn't know about the `class foo` any more.

When you do `foo_in_var=foo()` then namespace with `bar` is `foo -> class foo` and `foo_in_var -> implementation of foo()` still

Comment: What you said above should apply to `bar = bar()` as well, why it doesn't?

Comment: Good question. I think its because of the way a class is compiled basically packaging up all the code at once, vs. lines run in a file executing as they go. You should look at the link in wankata's answer to https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value which explains in more detail

Comment: See this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451827/python-local-variable-compile-principle. The basic explanation is that once the python compiler sees `foo = foo()` in the `bar` class, it categories `foo` as a local variable and cannot access the global variable `foo`. Whereas when the line `bar=bar()` is executed, the pointer to `bar ` is retrieved to call `bar()` and then reassigned in that order