# Python: Is variable stores the object's address?

Tags: python

In Python we declare and assign a variable like this:

```
a = 100
```

Most tutorials say a variable `a` now refers to the `int` object `100`.

Does that mean the variable `a` contains the address where an `int` object is stored ?

Comment: Indirectly somewhere behind the scenes yes. Not that it would concern you in userland code, since you have no direct access to memory.

Comment: Variables don't store anything in Python. Python doesn't really have variables, it has names which are stored in a dictionary.

Comment: yes it points to the address where 100 located

Comment: Alright, awesome consistency among comments here. :-D

Comment: @deceze Yes, I mean behind the scenes. So it acts like a pointer?

Comment: @deceze lol! To my understanding Python does bind names to variables however it does not work like pointers in C.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: @Cody You must not think of Python variables as pointers à la C, no.

Comment: @deceze that depends on what you mean by "think of Python variables as pointers". There is an element of truth in that perspective. For one thing, it explains how it is easy to create unintentional aliases when you do something like `a = b` with a mutable `b`.

Comment: @John Sure, but if you think in those terms then at some point you'll crash into things that *don't* work with variables that work with pointers, like pointer arithmetic. Thinking in terms that Python uses to describe itself has less cognitive overhead in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As John Coleman points out, python variables are just names in a dictionary, where the values pointed to by the keys are addresses. In the CPython implementation of python, you can find the memory address pointed to by a python variable by using the built-in function `id()`.

For more information about this dictionary refered to in my answer, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars)