# Create many new lists, to be populated from loop

Tags: python, list

What is the best way to generate empty, named lists? Do they need to be created manually? I had hoped the following would work:

```
fieldlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for fieldname in fieldlist:
    str(fieldname) + 'list' = []
```

Actual result:

```
  File "<interactive input>", line 2
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Desired result:

```
Alist = []
Blist = []
Clist = []
```

Comment: Python? You need to tag the language if you want language-specific assistance.

Comment: Probably the best way to do this is to use a dictionary.

Comment: @joechoj, did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept an answer (tick on left).

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary. There is rarely, if ever, a need to dynamically name variables from strings.

```
fieldlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']

d = {}

for fieldname in fieldlist:
    d[str(fieldname) + 'list'] = []

# {'Alist': [], 'Blist': [], 'Clist': []}
```

Comment: As I'm using numpy to do calculations with & on the arrays, I'd like to have them as standalone lists, and am pretty unused to working with dicts. Can I create them using a dict and then use dynamic assignment statements to split them out? Or perhaps it's best just to create them explicity, even if it's cumbersome?

Answer (score -1):

Using [globals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals). Also you could try locals(), vars(), then check this URL to understand [the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars).

PS: Thanks the corrections from @ShadowRanger.

**As API defined:**

**globals()**

*Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).*

**The codes will be like below if using globals():**

```
fieldlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for fieldname in fieldlist:
    name=str(fieldname) + 'list'
    globals()[name]=[]
print (Alist, Blist, Clist)
```

**Output:**

```
[] [] []
[Finished in 0.179s]
```

Comment: Modifications to the `locals()` dictionary [are explicitly documented as being a bad idea](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals); there is no guarantee that the modifications actually work. And in fact, it would not work in the general case on modern Python; the only reason it works here is because you did it at global scope, where `locals()` returns the same `dict` that `globals()` returns (and module globals really are stored in a mutable `dict`, so changing it works); inside a function body, the `dict` returned by `locals()` can't be mutated to do anything useful.