# Python the function locals() was changed by just calling it

Tags: python, function, local-variables

please read the two code ,and i find the only different is printing the locals() or not. But one of them is wrong.
Please help me , thanks

```py
import numpy as np

class Solution:
    def solve(self, f, a, b, n):
        x = np.linspace(a,b,n)
        # print(locals())
        loc = locals()
        fstr = '''
def fun(x):
    return %s
        ''' % f
        exec(fstr)
        # print(locals())
        fun  = loc['fun']
        y = fun(x)
        print(x,y,sep = '\n')

a = Solution()
a.solve('x+1',-5,5,5)
```

In this code ,I didn't print the locals()

if I only print it and write '#' in front of "fun  = loc['fun']" and "y = fun(x)" ,there is a key named 'fun' in the output of locals()

```py
import numpy as np

class Solution:
    def solve(self, f, a, b, n):
        x = np.linspace(a,b,n)
        # print(locals())
        loc = locals()
        fstr = '''
def fun(x):
    return %s
        ''' % f
        exec(fstr)
        print(locals())
        fun  = loc['fun']
        y = fun(x)
        print(x,y,sep = '\n')

a = Solution()
a.solve('x+1',-5,5,5)
```

But in this code ,i can't find the key named 'fun' in the output of locals()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 20, in <module>
    a.solve('x+1',-5,5,5)
  File "tmp.py", line 15, in solve
    fun  = loc['fun']
KeyError: 'fun'
```

All of this seem that "fun  = loc['fun']" and "y = fun(x)" determine the output of locals()

but i think it is impossible for python that latter code can change the front code

Comment: This Question is a possible duplicate of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars). please check that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that happens with `locals()`. `locals()` is confusing and not well documented.

Calling `locals()` repeatedly in the same stack frame returns the same dict every time, and every call to `locals()` *updates* that dict with the current values of local (or closure) variables. The dict is attached to the stack frame as its `f_locals` attribute, and accessing that attribute will also update the dict.

To use `locals()` safely without the values changing unpredictably, you should copy the returned dict:

```
current_locals = locals().copy()
```

Otherwise, even running your code in a debugger could change its behavior, since debuggers typically access `f_locals` to inspect local variables.

---

Also, trying to `exec` code that assigns any variables in a local scope is officially unsupported and behaves weirdly, and `def` counts as an assignment. You shouldn't use `exec` for this anyway.

Comment: Thanks your answer! Would you mean that use locals() may change the value of itself ? But if i change the code "fun = loc['fun']" and "y = fun(x)" to "funn = loc['fun']" and "y = funn(x)" ,which mean i change the name of the function , it can run.Could tell me why?

Comment: @YJSchaf: Python no longer has an empty "real" `fun` variable to copy the non-value over the `'fun'` entry in `locals()` once you change that.

Comment: As you say , when I want to change the value of fun , 'fun' in locals() was changed earlier. 
But if i write 'k =  copy.deepcopy(locals()['fun']) ' and 'fun = k' , it still is error.
I am confused that I have copied the locals()['fun'] to a new address, and the change of 'fun' will
not change the value of k, but it still error. I print(id(k)) and print(id(locals()['fun'])) then 
find that they are same ! Does copy.deepcopy not work?

Comment: I know that using exce() and locals() is not supported. But I really want to try to 
use exec to write a subfunction in a function such that this subfunction
can be called in the function instead of everywhere. I don't know how to write it.
Could you tell me a batter mothed without using locals() to approach that?
PS : please forgive my poor English , which sometimes I may misunderstand your mean :P