# browser 'window' object equivalent in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I learned that all variables, function, namespace in global scope becomes a property of `window` object offered from browser, which is accessible in Javascript through console. Is there any object similar to this in Python?

Comment: you want to search the web for "Python global namespace". The tl;dr is that Python has [locals(), globals(), and vars()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars)

Comment: This is quite a strange question, is it purely for the sake of learning?

Comment: @AMC Yeah, this question wasn't out of any practical need.

Comment: Python doesn't run in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary that contains all global variables, maybe similar to what you are looking for.

```py
globals()
> {'__builtins__': ... }

type(globals())
> <class 'dict'>
```

You may also interested in

- `dir()`: list of scoped variables
- `locals()`:dictionary of local variables