# Is there a javascript's window like object in python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I mean in javascript it is possible to create a variable accessible by everywhere in everyfile by assigning property to window object:

```
window.myVar = 'hello'
```

And use it like:

```
console.log(myVar)
```

[browser 'window' object equivalent in Python? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59656102/13449712) doesn't answer my question because assigning to `globals()` doesn't make it accessible from other files.

(I know global variables are *bad*)

Comment: You could create your own God-object that you assign to. Just create a class (or use a dictionary), place that in a file, then import the file and use that object as needed. [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=namespace#types.SimpleNamespace) may be a good tool to try.

Comment: What do you mean by accessible in "other files" ?

Comment: @TomLee https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mayer-gsbwf?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Don't think there is something like that for python, but you can consider sending the variable value from one file to another when needing to process the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign them to `__builtins__`:

`main.py`

```
__builtins__.my_var = 'Hello!'
import other
```

`other.py`

```
print(my_var)
```

Outputs: `Hello!`