# why is a functions parameter not fully the same inside and outside of the function

Tags: python-3.x

Why is a variable interpreted differently when inserted into a function?

```
my_variable = ['list_item1','another_list_item']

var_name = [ i for i, a in locals().items() if a == my_variable][0]
print("The variable name is:", var_name)

def print_and_logging(input):
    var_name = [ i for i, a in locals().items() if a == input][0]
    print("The variable name is:", var_name)
print_and_logging(my_variable)


#Output
'''
The variable name is: my_variable
The variable name is: input
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this.

*my_variable* is the name by which you refer to an object, specifically an array containing two strings, `['list_item1','another_list_item']`

This name exists in the outermost context of your code, the global namespace.

Now, when you are calling the function *print_and_logging* with the name *my_variable* as argument, what you are passing to it is not the name, but the **object** to which the name refers. The object is hence introduced in the context of the function, which forms a local namespace. The name by which the array object is introduced into (and therefore known to) this namespace is *input*. But that is still the same object.

If you experiment a bit more, you'll find that you can actually use the name *my_variable* inside your function, but that the name *input* is unknown outside of the function.

I think you'll find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars#answer-7969953) informative. Going forward, you might also want to make research on the concept of *namespace* and look *how arguments are passed* in python.