# Choosing the Function Dynamically

Tags: python

I've got some code that looks like the following:

```
if command == 'a':
    do_a(a, b, c)
elif command == 'b':
    do_b(a, b, c)
elif command == 'c':
    do_c(a, b, c)
```

How can I replace this type of thing with something more elegant? Perhaps, something along the lines of do_[command](a, b, c) where the function that is called is dependent upon the command?

Is it even possible?

Comment: You may want to learn more about Python closures http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/generators.html and `lambda` and Python `eval`  http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#eval (but don't abuse of `eval`)

Comment: Something like `eval('do_'+command)(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a dict of functions. Avoid `eval` if at all possible.

Comment: Don't use `eval` for this. Eval is useful for code generation (dynamically defining functions/classes) in things like the `namedtuple()` implementation where building a class using a low-level API would be needlessly complex and obscure the intent of the code. Here you're not dynamically defining anything, and `eval` would make the intent less clear.

Comment: **Do not ever use `eval` for any data that could possibly ever come, in whole or in part, from outside of the program. It is a security hole that allows the author of that data to run arbitrary Python code on your computer. No, you cannot properly sandbox it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that using "reflection", calling the function by string name, like explained here:

[Python: call a function from string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936572/python-call-a-function-from-string-name)

**BUT**

That wouldn't be more elegant, it would be less readable, and easier to screw up if you don't have absolute control over what's passed as `command`.

Your version is just fine:

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> Simple is better than complex.

If you really want to avoid the `elif`'s I would go with the `dict` of functions approach that was suggested in the comments.

Keep away from eval for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can store commands in a dict and lookup when needed:

```
In [15]: commands = {'mul': lambda x,y: x*y,
                     'add': lambda x,y: x+y}

In [16]: commands['mul'](3,4)
Out[16]: 12

In [17]: commands['add'](3,4)
Out[17]: 7

In [18]: command = 'add'; vars = (4,5)
In [19]: commands[command](*vars)
Out[19]: 9
```

you should check whether a `command` indeed is in `commands`:

```
if command in commands:
    commands[command]()
else:
    # handle error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def do(fname):
    return {'a':do_a, 'b':do_b, 'c':do_c}.get(fname)

def do_a(x,y,z): return x + y + z
def do_b(x,y,z): pass
def do_c(x,y,z): pass
```

Usage:

```
do('a')(1,2,3)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for a better solution from others but:

```
def dispatch(cmd, *args):
   globals()['do_' + cmd](*args)

def do_a(a, b, c):
```

Usage:

```
dispatch('a', 1, 2, 3)
```

Obviously not robust but `dispatch` could make sure that the function exists.

Possibly a nice way would be to use decorators.

```
@command()
def do_a(a,b,c):
    ...

@command("do_x")
def myfunc(a, b, c):
   ...
```

Your decorator could maintain the dispatch lookup table etc.

It depends how worried you are that there might be a need to use existing functions or worry about name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, here souce can be any generic module path ending with function name like
module.funcname

So a sample call would look like convertStringToFunction(module.funcname)

```
def import_module(name):
    mod = __import__(name)
    components = name.split('.')
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp)
return mod

def convertStringToFunction(source):
    tempArr = source.rsplit('.',1)
    mod = import_module(tempArr[0])
    func = getattr(mod, tempArr[1])
    return func
```