# How to access a model with its name in a string in django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I want to access to a model and its attribute that I defined in my django app via string name.
I found these two solutions but they are not fit to my question.

[How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

[Python: call a function from string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936572/python-call-a-function-from-string-name)

for example:
models.py

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now, I have "Foo.var2" string and I want to access to Foo model and filter in its var2 field.

Comment: How did you get that string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getattr` on the module containing the model, and then apply the same on the model to get the field in the model:

```
from app_name import models

s = "Foo.var2"
attrs = s.split('.')

my_model = my_field = None
# get attribute from module
if hasattr(models, attrs[0]):
    my_model = getattr(models, attrs[0])

    # get attribute from model
    if hasattr(my_model, attrs[1]):
        my_field = getattr(my_model, attrs[1])

# and then your query
if my_model and my_field:
    q = my_model.objects.filter(my_field="some string literal for filtering")
```