# How do I convert a python string that I'm getting from the user to a function name

Tags: python

I'm taking in an input from the user and storing it in a variable called videoType.

My question is, how do I take the string the user gives to videoType and convert that into a function name that I already have defined along with many others in python?

Ex.
user input: "get_MPEG()"
which is stored in videoType

And I would use that input as a function name.

Comment: Create a dictionary from strings to your functions.

Comment: if it's in another module `getattr(module, "method_name")()` but if it is in the same module, you have to do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936588/5203563, but could be dangerous as mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a dictionary. The keys to the dictionary are user inputs, the values are functions. Something like this:

```
def compliment():
    print("You look nice today.")

def insult():
    print("You look awful today.")

def default_function():
    print("Sorry, I don't know what you mean")

functions = {
    "compliment": compliment,
    "nice": compliment, # aliased command
    "insult": insult,
    "mean": insult,
}

videoType = input("What shall I do? ")
functions.get(videoType, default_function)()
```

Whatever you do, do NOT directly convert the user's input to code. Consider what happens if the user inputs `os.system('rm -rf' /)` as the name of his function!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a dictionary mapping function names to their corresponding functions:

```
def foo():
    print('foo called')

def bar():
    print('bar called')


exposed_functions = {
    'foo': foo,
    'bar': bar
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = 'foo'  # Pretend the user passed you this string
    function = exposed_functions[user_input]
    function()
```

This approach may seem redundant but you probably don't want the user to pass in a function like `exit()` and shut down your interpreter or even something like `__import__('os').system('rm -Rf --no-preserve-root /')` and do more harm.
Therefore, a whitelist is your best choice. To make it simpler, you can create a decorator to do all of this for you:

```
import functools

exposed_functions = {}

def expose(*names):
    def decorator(function):
        for name in (names or [function.__name__]):
            exposed_functions[name] = function

        return function

    return decorator

@expose()  # `name` is automatically extracted out of the function
def foo():
    print('foo called')

@expose('bar', 'baz')  # binds to both `bar` and `baz`
def bar():
    print('bar called')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = 'baz'  # Pretend the user passed you this string
    function = exposed_functions[user_input]
    function()
```

Comment: The decorator is a good idea!

Comment: do I not need parantheses around the function names in the dictionary for your first example, for example 'foo' : foo()

Comment: @KenB: `foo` is the function itself, `foo()` is the result of calling your function. You don't need to call the function, just reference it. For example, `x = foo; x()` is the same as `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary to access all the defined top-level functions (as well as other objects) in a module

```
def hello():
    print('hello')


videoType = input("Name a function")
globals()[videoType)()
```