# Can you convert list component into a function?

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying an hackerrank problem : String Validators

I actually solved the question but i'm trying a different approach on it.

Such as:

```
list=['isalnum()','isalpha()','isdigit()','islower()','isupper()']

for l in list:

    count =0

    for i in range(len(s)+1):
        a=i.l

        if a==1:
            count+=1

        if count !=0:
            print(False)
        elif count >0:
            print(True)
```

Is there any way that I can convert components inside the list as a function and use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: call a function from string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936572/python-call-a-function-from-string-name)

Answer (score 1):

In python you can actually make a list of function:
if you have your array looking like this:

```
list=[isalnum,isalpha, isdigit, islower, isupper]
```

if you type

```
list[0]()
```

the function isalnum will be executed, obviously if they take parameters you can also pass parameters

in case you want the members of your list to be like you wrote:

```
list=['isalnum()','isalpha()','isdigit()','islower()','isupper()']
```

you can use the function eval() even if i don't suggest it:

```
eval(list[0])
```

will evaluate the string as a line of code and execute the function isalnum()