# how to Implement process_deque(commands) to test my Deque function?

Tags: python, data-structures, deque

Firstly, I need to implementing a Deque Function.

**push_front** adds a key to the head of the deque

**push_back** adds a key to the tail of the deque

**pop_front** extracts a key from the head of the deque and returns it

**pop_back** extracts a key from the tail of the deque and returns it

**front** returns head element without removing it

**back** returns tail element without removing it

**size** returns number of the elements in the deque

**clear** removes all elements from the deque

Implement Deque class with this methods and error handling. For pop_frontpop_front, pop_backpop_back, front, back the method has to check are there elements in the deque. If it is empty the method has to return string "error" instead of a numeric value.

**push_front**, **push_back**, **clear** methods has to return string "ok".

Finally Implement process_deque(commands) which takes commands list and returns a list of answers to each command.

```
class Deque:

    def __init__(self, max_len = 60000):
        self.max_len = max_len + 1
        self.queue = [0] * self.max_len
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0


    def push_front(self, key):
        self.queue[self.head] = key
        self.head= (self.head - 1) % self.max_len
        return "ok"

    def push_back(self, key):
        self.queue[self.tail] = key
        self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.max_len
        return "ok"


    def pop_front(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            res = self.queue[self.head]
            self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.max_len
            return res

    def pop_back(self):
        res = self.queue[self.tail]
        self.tail = (self.tail - 1) % self.max_len
        return res

    def front(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.queue[self.head]

    def back(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.queue[self.tail]

    def clear(self):
        self.queue = []
        return "ok"


    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)


def process_deque(commands):


if __name__ == "__main__": # ***This is the 3 test case***
    test_cmd = ["push_front 1", "push_front 2", "push_back 6", "front", "back", "clear", "size", "back"]
    # should print ["ok", "ok", "ok", 2, 6, "ok", 0, "error"]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))

    test_cmd = ["pop_front", "back", "push_back 2", "size"]
    # should print ["error", "error", "ok", 1]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))

    test_cmd = ["push_back 1", "push_front 10", "push_front 4", "push_front 5", "back", "pop_back", "pop_back", "back"]
    # should print ["ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", 1, 1, 10, 4]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))
```

I am not sure how to implementing the process_deque(commands) to test the case.

Thanks.

I just adjust my Deque function, the below code is much more clean, since I don't know how to implementing the process_deque(commands), so i did not test it at all.

```
class Deque:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item = []


    def push_front(self, key):
        self.item.append(key)
        return "ok"

    def push_back(self, key):
        self.items.insert(0,key)
        return "ok"


    def pop_front(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            self.items.pop()

    def pop_back(self):
        return self.items.pop(0)

    def front(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.item[0]

    def back(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.item[-1]

    def clear(self):
        self.queue = []
        return "ok"


    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getattr` method to get the method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936572/python-call-a-function-from-string-name)

```py
def process_deque(commands):
    d = Deque()
    output = []
    for each_command in commands:
        splitted = each_command.split(" ")
        method_name = splitted[0]
        arg = splitted[1] if len(splitted)==2 else None
        method = getattr(d, method_name)
        if(arg):
            output.append(method(arg))
        else:
            output.append(method())
    return output
```

But your `deque` class methods implementations are **not correct**.
This is not in the scope of this question so to show that the above method is correct I am using python `list` which itself can act as a `deque`.

```py
class Deque:

    def __init__(self, max_len = 60000):
#         self.max_len = max_len + 1
#         self.queue = [0] * self.max_len
#         self.head = 0
#         self.tail = 0
        self.queue = []


    def push_front(self, key):
#         self.queue[self.head] = key
#         self.head= (self.head - 1) % self.max_len
        self.queue.insert(0, key)
        return "ok"

    def push_back(self, key):
#         self.queue[self.tail] = key
#         self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.max_len
        self.queue.append(key)
        return "ok"


    def pop_front(self):
#         if self.head == self.tail:
#             return "error"
#         else:
#             res = self.queue[self.head]
#             self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.max_len
#             return res
        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            return "error"
        else:
            res = self.queue.pop(0)
            return res

    def pop_back(self):
#         res = self.queue[self.tail]
#         self.tail = (self.tail - 1) % self.max_len
        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            return "error"
        else:
            res = self.queue.pop()
            return res
        return res

    def front(self):
        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.queue[0]

    def back(self):
        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            return "error"
        else:
            return self.queue[-1]

    def clear(self):
        self.queue.clear()
        return "ok"


    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)


def process_deque(commands):
    d = Deque()
    output = []
    for each_command in commands:
        splitted = each_command.split(" ")
        method_name = splitted[0]
        arg = splitted[1] if len(splitted)==2 else None
        method = getattr(d, method_name)
        if(arg):
            output.append(method(arg))
        else:
            output.append(method())
    return output
        


if __name__ == "__main__": # ***This is the 3 test case***
    test_cmd = ["push_front 1", "push_front 2", "push_back 6", "front", "back", "clear", "size", "back"]
    # should print ["ok", "ok", "ok", 2, 6, "ok", 0, "error"]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))

    test_cmd = ["pop_front", "back", "push_back 2", "size"]
    # should print ["error", "error", "ok", 1]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))

    test_cmd = ["push_back 1", "push_front 10", "push_front 4", "push_front 5", "back", "pop_back", "pop_back", "back"]
    # should print ["ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", 1, 1, 10, 4]
    print(process_deque(test_cmd))
```

output

```
['ok', 'ok', 'ok', '2', '6', 'ok', 0, 'error']
['error', 'error', 'ok', 1]
['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', '1', '1', '10', '4']
```

Comment: @AcatAdog don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem so it won't pop again :)